# R: Scope in nested functions, part 2: nested do.call's

Tags: r, scope, nested, iteration, numerical-integration

Here I have a real question and a greatly simplified question that may or may not encapsulate my confusion about the first question.

The function `multi_quad` below is supposed to integrate `dfun`, here `dgb2` from the GB2 package, over the limits from lower bound `lb` to upper bound `ub`. The base-R `integrate` function successfully does this integration for the parameter values and limits given here, but fails for ub=4.55e8 or more. I have a question posted about this problem, [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267737/r-convergence-problems-with-numerical-integration) [R: Convergence problems with numerical integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267737/r-convergence-problems-with-numerical-integration)

I an effort to solve the convergence problem, I have the function `multi_quad`, below, which is supposed to attempt integration with various alternative quadrature methods from the pracma package. I am using `safely( )` from the purrr package in an attempt to try all the methods, return values if they converge, and error messages otherwise.

For each iteration of `map`, I get an error that argument `"lb" is missing, with no default`. Here the both the enclosing and the calling environment of the outer do.call is the execution environment of m_quad, and both the enclosing and the calling environment of m_quad is the execution environment of multi_quad. Since I supply `multi_quad` with a value for `lb`, I expect `m_quad` and `do.call` to be able to find it, regardless of how `lb` in the outer do.call is scoped. This is incorrect, and I do not know why.

```
library(GB2)
library(pracma)
library(purr)

multi_quad <- function(dfun, params, lb, ub){
  m_quad <- function(q_method, dfun, params, lb, ub){
    do.call(what=q_method, 
            args=list(f=function(X){do.call(what=dfun, args=params)}, a=lb, b=ub))
    }
  safe_m_quad <- safely(m_quad)
  q_methods<- list("quadgk",  "quadcc",  "simpadpt", "renshaw", "quadgr") %>% 
    map(safe_m_quad)  -> out
  out
}

GB2_params <- list(shape1 = 3.652, scale = 65797, shape2 = 0.3, shape3 = 0.8356)

results <- multi_quad(dfun=dgb2, params=GB2_params, lb=1, ub=3e8)

results
```

Below is a vastly simplified example where I think my expectations of when and how an inner function can find a value supplied to a calling function are frustrated in a similar way. Here the variables with names starting in "extra" are to prevent positional matching.

In this example, the execution environment of `fa` is both the calling and the enclosing environment of `fb`. Why isn't the value of `arg1`, under that name, from `fa` in scope for `arg1` of `fb`? Whether `fb`'s `arg1` is looking for `arg1` in its calling environment or it's enclosing environment, or in `fb`'s execution environment and up from there, in every case it should arrive in `fa`'s execution environment. But it doesn't. Why is this? Where is it looking instead?

```
fa <- function(extra0=0, arg1, extra2=2){
  extra0
  extra2
  fb(arg1)
  fb <- function(extra3=3, arg1){
    extra3
    print(arg1)}  
}

fa(arg1=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) For me, `integrate` works up to 7.0e08. Think of it what huge integration domain this is. You're applying functions from *pracma* that are more meant as method demonstrations, not for pretentious tests. `quadgk`is similar to `integrate` and works up to 1.0e09, the `integral` function in *pracma* up to 1.0e10 !

If you want to integrate over the unbounded interval `[0. Inf]`, then `integrate` will not work again. But `integral` recognizes the unboundedness and reverts to some other approach:

```
fun = function(x) dgb2(x, shape1 = 3.652, scale = 65797,
                          shape2 = 0.3, shape3 = 0.8356)
pracma::integral(fun, 0, Inf)
## For infinite domains Gauss integration is applied!
## [1] 1
```

It actually employs `pracma::quadinf` that transforms the infinite domain into a finite domain before applying a Gaussian Quadrature rule.

(2) In your simplified text example, the first bug is that you call `fb(arg1)` before having defined it. If you put `fb(arg1)` after the function definition, `arg1` will be assigned to `extra3` and the parameter `arg1` is still undefined.

A possible correction could be:

```
fa <- function(extra0=0, arg1, extra2=2){
    fb <- function(extra3=3, arg1){
        print(arg1)
    }
    fb(arg1 = arg1)
}

fa(arg1=1)
## [1] 1
```

Or change `fb` to `fb <- function(arg1, extra3=3) {...}`.
What the lines `extra0`, `extra1`, etc. are good for remains unclear.

(3) Added to provide some reasonable integral value:

Intgral functions `integral` and `quadgk` are able to return reasonable values for intervals up 5e08 and larger by selecting appropriate parameters.

```
I1 = integrate(fun, 0, 5.0e08, rel.tol=1e-14, subdivisions=1000)$value; I1 - 1
## [1] -4.792833e-13

I2 = integral(fun, 0, 5.0e08, reltol=1e-14); I2 -1
## [1] -4.775069e-13

I3 = quadgk(fun, 0, 5.0e08, tol=1e-14); I3 - 1
## [1] -4.773959e-13
```

So that we get the following integral values:

```
| Function          | Value             |
|-------------------|-------------------|
| stats::integrate  | 0.999999999999521 |
| pracma::integral  | 0.999999999999522 |
| pracma::quadgk    | 0.999999999999523 |
```

These functions use similar "adaptive Gaussian quadrature" rules, so no wonder they return similar results. Other competely different integration routines may come up with (slightly ?) different results.

Comment: Thanks @HansW!  You state that I am using “functions from pracma that are more meant as method demonstrations, not for pretentious tests.” Does you imply that there are integration functions in some other package that _are_ meant for pretentious tests? Because Forbes reported that in 2017 Amazon’s Jeff Bezos had wealth of $112 billion, and assuming a nominal return of 10%, which would be a lowball number for Bezos, I know my population contains someone with income over 1e10, I also need additional wiggle room for projection or for exploring the parameter space.

Comment: I know these numbers seem cosmological, but that is because, well, they are. Besos alone has the same income as a bit less than 200,000 median households, or roughly half a million typical U.S. citizens .

Comment: Please have a look at the integration routines on the
[NumericalMathematics](https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=NumericalMathematics) 
Task View. I think there are not so many alternatves; if someone finds one, let me know.  
I have added some code to the answer above in an attempt to return a usable integral value for a larger domain.